# I want to find exclude a particular category from the Foursquare API JSON how can I do it in RUBY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foursquare

i want to find exclude a particular category from the ***foursquare*** api *json* how can i do it in **ruby**? in case i want to exclude Amphitheater and its sub categories?

```
"response": {
"categories": [
  {
    "id": "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259",
    "name": "Arts & Entertainment",
    "icon": {
      "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
      "suffix": ".png"
    },
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "56aa371be4b08b9a8d5734db",
        "name": "Amphitheater",
        "categories": [{
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d134941735",
            "name": "Dance Studio",
            categories[sub categories #edited]
            ]
      }
```

Comment: Your json is correct??

Comment: Hi, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like your shift key isn't working reliably. "i" should be "I", "api" is "API", "json" is "JSON", "ruby" is "Ruby". Stack Overflow isn't a discussion list, it's an online reference book where grammar and spelling count. Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Show us your attempt toward solving this. Without it it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exclude categories from the API response. You will have to check the JSON after it's received from Foursquare and remove any venues with a categoryId you don't want. See the categoryIds here: https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree